# Creating a Nested XML File for SubMenu Categories for a dropdown box

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I need a XML file for my drop down box with sub menu.

For Example:

```
<Fruits>
<Apple>
<Price>100</Price>
</Apple>


<Mango>
<Price>100</Price>
</Mango>

</Fruits>
```

Now For this Apple I need a submenu such as color, country etc..,

So on hover of apple I am going to show the submenu Xml file items.

All data should be integrated in one XML file only,

Please do the needful

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to store that kind of data inside a XML-file, then i would do something like this:

```
<Fruits>

<Apple>
<Price>100</Price>
<Colors>
    <Color>Green</Color>
    <Color>Red</Color>
    <Color>Yellow</Color>
</Colors>
<Origin>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <Country>Italy</Country>
    <Country>Argentina</Country>
</Origin>
</Apple>

</Fruits>
```

If you're asking about your dropdown menu, please provide us with some more information